# setNavigationBarHidden:NO is appearing when dismissed

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6, uinavigationbar

I want to make the Navigation Bar disappear when dismissed with the close button OR make the Navigation Bar hide when close the screen.

Here's the code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:FALSE ];

    self.title=@"Cookie Policy";

    NSString *htmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Cookie Policy" ofType:@"html"];
    NSString* htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:htmlFile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    [webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];



    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 32);
    button.titleLabel.font=[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15];
    [button setTitle:@"X" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(openView) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    UIBarButtonItem *barButton=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] init];
    [barButton setCustomView:button];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=barButton;

}
```

When press **setTitle:@"X"**, I see the Navigation Bar on all other screens in the UI. In other words, the Navigation Bar is overlapping (brought to front) in all other screens. I use storyboard for all screens. I think the change has to be made in code.

Please advice

Comment: You have to write code in every ViewController to hide or show the navigation bar. I you change the default behaviour of Navigation Bar in middle of your project.

Comment: RahulMishra, what would be the code?

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the issue by adding this line of code:

```
    _nav.navigationBarHidden = YES;
```

Did not need to touch anything in Storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Select every ViewController on storyboard and change `Top Bar` from inferred to none on those you don't want the bar visible. See picture:

[image]

By the way, the `FALSE` on your first line is wrong. There is no `FALSE` on Objective-C. Its `YES` or `NO`.

Comment: SpaceDog, I tried what you suggested and all Top Bar metrics has been set to NONE in all ViewControllers as part of the Storyboard, but it seems like the Top Bar is still appearing in all screens. I need to have at least 10 rep points to post a photo.

Comment: Return to your storyboard and set the navigation Controller top bar to translucent navigation bar or another one. The navigation controller is the first item on your storyboard. You cannot set that to NONE. You have to set all to none except this one.

Comment: Ok, what you suggest is working (when set the Top Bar to none) when dismiss the alert. But if I do not dismiss it and display it and then when I close it, the top bar is appearing back again.